# Select text wrapped in quotation marks

Tags: phpstorm

Is it possible to select text wrapped in quotation marks or other signs in PhpStorm (2016)?

I.e.

```
"Here is some code"
```

When I use shortcut I want to select all what is in quotation marks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends on the context: what the actual language is. It works fine for PHP & JavaScript but does not seem to do anything special in HTML (as `"` are treated as part of the actual text).

1. Place caret inside of such a string.
2. Use `Edit | Extend Selection` (<kbd>Ctrl + W</kbd> on Windows/Linux using Default keymap; on Mac it most likely will be <kbd>Alt + Arrow Up</kbd> or similar)
3. You will need to use that shortcut a few times in a row (at least 2 times if there are more than one word in a string) until it selects the whole string content. That's because this shortcut works in incremental mode: first the current word, then the whole sentence or other outer code construction and so on (each language can provide own boundaries of the "block").

Comment: I thought it only works with brackets... ;p Thanks! :)